# Calculate new date after calendar event drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a JavaScript/Math question.
I am stuck with one task for two days now and I guess I am complete idiot as I can't figure it out...[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkqz3.png)

I am creating a week calendar with shifts from 7am untill 8pm., but I can have shift which is for example 2 days long (or more).

The problem is that I can drag and drop the calendar event on the calendar and then I need to calculate new dateTo from dateFrom which I get from the div I placed it on.

The issues is that when I try to drag and drop the item to another time I need to place dateFrom to whenever I dragged it, but then I need to calculate hours so I get the same amount of time, but the problem is when the event is stretched over multiple days I need the event to finish next date after 7 am and not in the middle of the night. For example I had event from 3pm to 5pm of next day and then I moved it to 7pm of next day so I need the event to finish at 9 am of next day.

Does anyone has the same issue or solution for this?
Hope it makes sense, thank you very much.

Here is the code I am using right now, it almost works, but sometimes I get the wrong date/time (usually it removes 10 hours from date).

```
export function getCorrectDateAfterDrop(originalDateFrom, originalDateTo, dateFrom) {

    const NIGHT_TIME = 11;

    dateFrom = moment(dateFrom);
    originalDateTo = moment(originalDateTo);
    originalDateFrom = moment(originalDateFrom);

    let hoursDiff = moment.duration(originalDateTo.diff(originalDateFrom)).asHours();
    const sign = Math.sign(hoursDiff);

    if (originalDateTo.isAfter(moment(originalDateFrom).hours(20))) {
        hoursDiff = (hoursDiff > NIGHT_TIME) ? (hoursDiff - NIGHT_TIME) : hoursDiff;
    }

    let finalDateToBeChecked = moment(dateFrom).add((hoursDiff * sign), 'hours');
    let isDateFromSameAsDateTo = moment(dateFrom).isSame(finalDateToBeChecked, 'day');

    if (isDateFromSameAsDateTo && finalDateToBeChecked.hours() < 20) {
        // I think the problem is here, but I can't figure it out :D
        return finalDateToBeChecked.format();
    } else {
        const diffUntilShiftEnds = moment.duration(moment(dateFrom).hours(20).diff(dateFrom)).asHours();
        hoursDiff -= diffUntilShiftEnds;
        const finalDateFrom = moment(dateFrom).add(1, 'days').hours(7);
        const finalDateTo = moment(dateFrom).add(1, 'days').hours(7).add(hoursDiff, 'hours');
        return getCorrectDateAfterDrop(finalDateFrom, finalDateTo, finalDateFrom);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not fully understand your question, but I think something like the following should work:

```js
function getCorrectDateAfterDrop(originalDateFrom, originalDateTo, dateFrom) {
    return originalDateTo - originalDateFrom + dateFrom;
}


// verify it works:

var origFrom = Date.parse('01 Jan 2018 05:00:00');
var origTo = Date.parse('02 Jan 2018 07:00:00');
var newFrom = Date.parse('02 Jan 2018 01:00:00');
var newTo = getCorrectDateAfterDrop(origFrom, origTo, newFrom)

console.log((Date.parse('03 Jan 2018 03:00:00') === newTo)) // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, this would work, but what I need is that the event should not finish in the middle of the night, for example when you got 3 hours event from 7pm, it should finish at 9am of the next day. Thank you anyway for your quick answer